# In Jekyll How do I override auto-title casing?

Tags: markdown, jekyll

In Jekyll I have liquid syntax that loops over all posts and displays the `page.title`. In one post I have an acronym AAA. Unfortunately `page.title` titlecases the acronym to Aaa.

How do I make the AAA be capitalized in my loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by explicitly stating a title. Instead of letting Jekyll implicitly pull the title from the post filename, which works for other posts.

in my frontmatter:

```
---
title: Why AAA Would Benefit from Bitcoin
---
```